# std::ignore explanation of compiler errors

Tags: c++, parsing

I used std::ignore(1,',') before the first getline(iss,name,',') and received the error 'ignore' is undeclared in this namespace 'std'.

```
        if (myfile.is_open()){
 98     while ( getline (myfile,line) ) {
 99         //parse line
100         string myText(line);
101         istringstream iss(myText);
102         if(!(iss>>id)) id=0;
103
104         std::ignore(iss,1,',');
105         std::getline(iss,name,',');
106         std::getline(iss,status,',');
107         std::getline(iss,email,',');
108         cout<<name<<endl;
109         Student newStudent(id,name,status,email);
```

Why is it the getline functions work but the ignore doesnt?

Comment: Have you tried reading [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore)? That's not what `std::ignore` is for at all.

Comment: I know what I have incorrect all together. I was just trying something to see if I understood it wrong. First I tried std::ignore(1,',') and got the same error. But the answer below is exactly what I needed. The documentation doesn't address it in quite enough detail to help me completely.

Comment: FWIW, [searching in there](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=ignore&button=) is usually pretty good. In your case, the `std::istringstream` one is most relevant, but they're all pretty similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ignore` is a member function.

```
iss.ignore(1, ',');
```

Comment: BTW all he really needs is `iss.ignore()` since he wants to ignore only one character.